# How to find the list of aws service identifiers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

I'm working with aws and implementing CI/CD using their developer tools.  Each of the tools requires a service role, so I decided to just update my existing service role with the correct permissions.  The problem is I don't know where to find the list of values to use for each service.

Below I just guessed the right name after creating a role, but I prefer not to guess
[image]

I searched the docs and found [these names](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html) and I also tried using the **cli** to find the ids: `aws describe-services` or `aws help` but that list doesn't match.

**How do I find the values to update these policies?**

Comment: This is kind of unofficial [List of AWS Service Principals](https://gist.github.com/shortjared/4c1e3fe52bdfa47522cfe5b41e5d6f22) but constantly being updated by people.

Comment: @samtoddler Wow thanks, that is so useful, i'd definitely upvote that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on comments there is no official API. But there is an unofficial [List of AWS Service Principals](https://gist.github.com/shortjared/4c1e3fe52bdfa47522cfe5b41e5d6f22) been kind of maintained by the people.